# How to get username by userid on webservice (asmx) file?

Tags: c#, .net, web, service

I am trying to make a web service for the mobile. And I had problem to establish session. So I send the user ID when user login. So it can be used for future reference. And now I need to find a username using userid is their is a better way to do this on my web service?

Comment: Add your code to the question to make users help you better.

Comment: To find out "better way" we first need to understand whats your way...